# How to turn off eslint for node.js firebase functions project

Tags: firebase, eslint

When I created my firebase project, I enabled eslint. But now I wanted to disable it. is there a way to turn it off without initializing another project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I added this comment to the first line of the js file

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

And it works for now.